# PDE subscript notation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, notation

What does this notation mean in a PDE: $(u_xu_t)_{xx}$?
For example, I have checked that  $(u_xu_t)_x=u_{xx}u_{xt}$ so the product rule does not apply. However, it applies in the former case. What's the general rule?

Comment: Actually, $(u_xu_t)_x=u_{xx}u_t+u_xu_{tx}$.

Comment: The author uses it as above!

Comment: Subzero-273K : You claim to have checked that  $(u_xu_t)_x=u_{xx}u_{xt}$. Please, show your calculus for this supposed check.

Comment: @JJacquelin In the paper context

Comment: @Subzero-273K What is $u$ in the context? Is it solution of any equation?

Comment: Yes, a solution to a PDE. Used for different PDEs

Comment: @Subzero-273K Could you give the reference?

Comment: E.g. https://arxiv.org/pdf/1003.0287.pdf

Comment: Where does the author of the linked paper use the result in your original post?

Comment: @Kevin Compare the dKP equation elsewhere

Comment: Ok, could you, in your original post verify for us that $(u_t u_x)_x=u_{xx} u_{tx}$?

Comment: @Bran In the linked paper, the expression $u_{xt}=u_{yy}+(uu_x)_{x}$ is a PDE. It is not obtained as a particular case of any general differentiation rule for products. It probably results from the modeling of some physical phenomenon. I suspect that the same is true for the equality in the post.

Comment: @Bran: Don't confuse an equation with an identity. $(u_tu_x)_x=u_{tx}u_x+u_tu_{xx}$ is an identity which means that is is true any function $u(x,t)$. On the other hand $(u_tu_x)_x=u_{xx}u_{xt}$ which is an equation  is not true for any $u(x,t)$, but it is true for some particular functions solutions of the equation. So, the relationship  $(u_tu_x)_x=u_{xx}u_{xt}$ mut not be used everywhere for differents problems than the specific problem to which it is coming from.

Answer (score 0):

It means that, for a function $u=u(x,t)$, you are computing the following quantity
\begin{align*} \frac{\partial^2}{\partial x \partial x} \left( \frac{\partial u}{\partial x} \cdot \frac{\partial u}{\partial t} \right) = \frac{\partial}{\partial x} \left( \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x \partial x}\cdot \frac{\partial u}{\partial t} + \frac{\partial u}{\partial x} \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x \partial t} \right) \\
= \frac{\partial^3 u}{\partial x \partial x \partial x} \cdot \frac{\partial u}{\partial t} + 2\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x \partial x} \cdot \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x \partial t} + \frac{\partial u}{\partial x} \cdot \frac{\partial^3 u}{\partial x \partial x \partial t}
\end{align*}